# "Gifting" a house to a family member

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, gift-tax, housing, gifts

I bought a house for myself a few years ago with the profit from an investment, however as I was (still am) under 18 I had my mother buy it in her name. As I am nearing 18, I was wondering how I could get the house in my own name without having to pay large amounts of tax on it. Its current market value is around £350000.

Would "selling" me it for a few thousand pounds work?

Edit: It has been suggested that what I am proposing is tax fraud, however I am only hoping to avoid paying tax *thrice* (stamp duty I initially paid when buying the property, capital gains when selling it to myself, and stamp duty when buying it from my mother).

Comment: This seems like a comprehensive guide, but I'm unfamiliar with UK tax law to know for sure:  https://www.saga.co.uk/magazine/money/personal-finance/giving/what-you-need-to-know-about-signing-property-over-to-your-children

Comment: You should know that "not" committing fraud looks to the authorities the same as actually committing fraud. [Using "" seems to indicate that you believe what you are doing in essence does not match what you are intending. Weaseling out of tax is generally not as easy as winking].

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I'm not weaseling out of tax: I have already paid stamp duty when buying the property - not wanting to pay both capital gains tax and stamp duty again just to have it in my name is certainly not fraud...

Comment: If your mother gifts the house to you (i.e. does not receive anything in return) and there is no mortgage outstanding on the house then there isn't any Stamp Duty Land Tax (aka SDLT) to pay - see https://www.gov.uk/guidance/sdlt-transferring-ownership-of-land-or-property#gift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/registering-land-or-property-with-land-registry/transfer-ownership-of-your-property):

> You must tell HM Land Registry when you change the registered owner of
>   your property, for example if you’re transferring it into another
>   person’s name, or if you want to add your partner as a joint owner.

So it sounds like you can have your mom fill out some paperwork, pay a fee and it can be in your name. It might be beneficial to contact a lawyer (I believe they are called solicitors in the UK?) to work out the finer details.